# Как округлять переменные типа Date

Tags: c#, дата

Есть данные со `СКУД`. Это `время входа` и `время выхода`. Время работы организации с `8 до 17:00` (обед не считаем). Есть переменные - `таймаут1 - 25 минут` и `таймаут2 - 55 минут`(ниже объясню зачем они). Надо посчитать **фактическое** время работы. Время работы организации "Рога и копыта" с 08:00 до 17:00

Допустим человек пришел в `8:01`  и ушел в `17:40`. Так как он пришел в `8:01` и количество минут `01 < 25(таймаут1)`,то время входа будет `08:00`. Время выхода `17:40`. `40 > 25(таймаут1)` но меньша `55(таймаут2)` - поэтому округляем до `30` (до получаса). Получается что фактическое время работы с `08:00` по `17:30`. Это простейший алгоритм и его перенос в код не составит проблем.

Проблемы возникают если во времени прихода или ухода будут часы.
Допустим если человек пришел в `10:25` и ушел в `16:45`. Как посчитать его фактическое время?

Comment: я правильно понял, что вам нужно фиксировать время прихода и ухода с точностью до 30 минут?

Comment: А для таких случаев (разница 2:25) алгоритм расчёта не описан. Как считать то, что неизвестно как считать?

Comment: @rdorn,  Фиксация времени это сумма разниц между фактическим временем начала работы и фактическим временем его окончания. Точность не совсем 30 минут. До 25 минут чтобы округление шло в сторону получаса. И если будет время допустим 45 минут, то так как оно больше получаса, но меньше 2-ого таймаута - 55 минут. Поэтому его тоже "округляем" до получаса

Comment: По вашему алгоритму то, что он пришел в 10:25 и ушел в 16:45 означает, что время прихода и ухода будет отмечено как 10:30 и 16:30.  Дальше в `TimeSpan` и в нужные интервалы. Или что-то не так?

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
DateTime rounded = time.AddMilliseconds(-time.Millisecond).AddSeconds(-time.Second);
int minutes = rounded.Minute < 25 ? 0 : rounded.Minute > 55 ? 60 : 30;
rounded = rounded.AddMinutes(minutes - rounded.Minute);
```

Часы сами увеличатся, если мы добавим 60.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Руслан. В вашем коде идет просто округление, а мне хотелось бы высчитать фактическое время.  фактическое время = округленное время выхода - округленное время входа

Comment: @Radzhab так и посчитайте, `TimeSpan workingTime = time2 - time1;` где time1, time2 - округленное время